# How to fetch attribute value from map?

Tags: java

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> finmap = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(payload, Map.class);
System.err.println("finmap"+finmap);
```

```
Output: finmap{orderTaskDryRun=[{dateTime=2023-02-22, dryRunFlag=false, deploymentType=null, peSubInterface=5000, rollbackOutput={}, errorDescription=null, generateOutput={}, errorCode=null, actionCode=Provide, peInterface=TenGigabitEthernet1/0/0, srimsOrderId=585, status=In Progress}]}
```

From finmap, I need to fetch peInterface and pesubInterface value?

```java
String peInterface= null != finmap ? (String)finmap.get("peInterface"):"";
String pesubInterface = null != finmap ? (String)finmap.get("pesubInterface"):"";

System.err.println("peInterface:" + peInterface);
System.err.println("peSubInterface:" + peSubInterface);
```

I tried this but values are coming as null only for peinterface and pesubinterface.

Comment: (String)finmap.get("peInterface"):"";- this would not fetch annything. As you are trying to get a value of the key 'peInterface' in a Map.That doesn't exists.  I would suggest to create a model class of orderTaskDryRun fields and then having a map of Map<String, <Model Class>>. This way you can easily fetch the values.

Answer (score 1):

`get("pesubInterface")` should be `get("peSubInterface")`

Answer (score 0):

First things first: is the structure of the payload always the same? If so let's create a proper class representing the data instead of a `Map<String, Object>` which is awkward in usage.

Also notice, that the map has only a single key `orderTaskDryRun` which maps to an array of objects. Thus, you have to first get the array using the `orderTaskDryRunKey`, then the first element from the array, and only then a key (field) from the object from the array.

So, with the assumption that the data format won't vary, I'd model it as a class:

```java
public class FinMap {
  
  private final List<DryRunResult> orderTaskDryRun;

  // constructor and getters skipped for brevity
}

public class DryRunResult {
  
  private final LocalDate dateTime; 
  private final boolean dryRunFlag;
  private final DeploymentType deploymentType;
  private final int peSubInterface;
  private final String peInterface;

  // other fields skipped for brevity, you should get the point by now ;-)
}
```

Not knowing the exact data model, it's hard for me to judge if the array will always have a single element, more than one element, or it may be empty - this is something you'll have to handle in your code. In the example  case:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
FinMap finmap = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(payload, FinMap.class);

finmap.getOrderTaskDryRun().get(0).getPeInterface();
finmap.getOrderTaskDryRun().get(0).getPeSubInterface();
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> finmap = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(payload, Map.class);
System.err.println("finmap" + finmap);
System.err.println(finmap.getClass());
List<Map<String, String>> submap = (List<Map<String, String>>) finmap.get("orderTaskDryRun");
System.err.println("submap:" + submap);
```

Output: Now from this submap how should i fetch attribute values for peinterface and pesubinterface.

```
submap:[{dateTime=2023-02-22, dryRunFlag=false, deploymentType=null, peSubInterface=5000, rollbackOutput={}, errorDescription=null, generateOutput={}, errorCode=null, actionCode=Provide, peInterface=TenGigabitEthernet1/0/0, srimsOrderId=585, status=In Progress}]
```